# Search using Update Panels

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

Is it possible to use an UpdatePanel that has like a few text boxes, and a search button, and then perhaps another UpdatePanel that has a gridview in it to return the results of what was searched. When the user clicks search it hides the boxes, and displays the gridview. Can I do this with UpdatePanels? I am using c# for my coding. Or should I be doing this another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one `UpdatePanel` in that case and setup a `Trigger` to your search `Button`.

Put only the controls that will be refreshed in your `UpdatePanel`.

Example:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchCriteria" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSearch" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="grdSearchResults" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Implement the `btnSearch_Click` function to execute your search and bind the results to the `GridView`.  The `UpdatePanel` will handle the ajax call and replacing of the HTML that the `GridView` will produce.

You want to keep as much out of the `UpdatePanel` as possible and only include what will actually change because it is transmitting that HTML with each update so it's a waste of resources if you are not actually doing anything to those controls with each action.  That is why a trigger is best to be used in this case which will hook the `UpdatePanel` to the `Click` event outside of the `UpdatePanel` scope.

Read up more on `UpdatePanel` and how triggers work on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you can do that with two `<asp:Panel>` controls inside the `<UpdatePanel>`.  One panel for the textboxes, and the other for the gridview.  You set which panel to show in the codebehind, depending on whether you're expecting your user to enter search criteria, or review the search results.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
You also could use just one update panel. Since you the Search Form (could be in a Panel) and the GridView inside the UpdatePanel.